# How do i make pictures next together with unordered list under them in a marquee

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists, marquee

As said in the title, im trying to find a way to add pictures with an unordered list inside a marquee something like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVmCa.png) . And this is what I currently have

```
<HTML>
<body>
<marquee>
<div>
<img src="img">
    <span class="caption"><ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul></span>
</div>
<div>
<img src="img">
    <span class="caption"><ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul></span>
</div>
</marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please improve your question? How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Note that the marquee tag is deprecated, see MDN.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Deprecated means that it should not be used on new websites. It is not in the current standard and although some browsers may still support it it could be withdrawn at any time see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: You also shouldn’t really have a ul as a child of a span element. You might find it useful to put your code through a validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the marquee tag is deprecated this snippet uses a slightly different method.

It has two copies of each of the marquee items and lays them out in a container which is a horizontal grid which takes up twice the width of the container (in this case, the viewport).

In this way we can translate the container 50% to the left and then repeat the animation - the second part of the container will be 'replaced' by the first and the movement will be continuous.

A second thing that had to be fixed was having a ul in a span. Instead the span has become a div.

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Banner</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .banner {
      width: 200vw;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
      gap: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      animation: move infinite 6s linear;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    @keyframes move {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
    }
    
    .banner>* {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .banner img {
      width: 10vh;
      height: 10vh;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .caption ul {
      padding-inline-start: 0;
    }
    
    .
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
      <div class="caption">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know that marquee is deprecated but is there a way I can use it instead of your code?

Comment: I expect so but I wouldn't myself use it in case it disappears off some browser some time.